# Unable to run Cassandra on Kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

I'm trying to run Cassandra on kubernetes.

One thing I understood is Cassandra is trying to access kubernetes api server on `port 443 (Secure Connection)` but I'm running api server on `non secure connection port 8080`.

Also there is `Has no permission to create /cassandra_data/data directory` error

Error (Cassandra pod log):

```
INFO  13:04:02 Getting endpoints from https://10.100.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/endpoints/cassandra
WARN  13:04:11 Request to kubernetes apiserver failed
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://10.100.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/endpoints/cassandra
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1628) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
    at io.k8s.cassandra.KubernetesSeedProvider.getSeeds(KubernetesSeedProvider.java:143) ~[kubernetes-cassandra.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:659) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:136) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:168) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:564) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:653) [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
INFO  13:04:11 JVM vendor/version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_95
WARN  13:04:11 OpenJDK is not recommended. Please upgrade to the newest Oracle Java release
INFO  13:04:11 Heap size: 526385152/526385152
INFO  13:04:11 Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 795136(776K) committed = 2555904(2496K) max = 50331648(49152K)
INFO  13:04:11 Eden Space Heap memory: init = 83886080(81920K) used = 79390336(77529K) committed = 83886080(81920K) max = 83886080(81920K)
INFO  13:04:11 Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 10485760(10240K) used = 0(0K) committed = 10485760(10240K) max = 10485760(10240K)
INFO  13:04:11 CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 432013312(421888K) used = 0(0K) committed = 432013312(421888K) max = 432013312(421888K)
INFO  13:04:11 CMS Perm Gen Non-heap memory: init = 21757952(21248K) used = 19488984(19032K) committed = 21757952(21248K) max = 174063616(169984K)
INFO  13:04:11 Classpath: /kubernetes-cassandra.jar:/etc/cassandra:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/airline-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-16.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/javax.inject.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stream-2.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.1.13.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core-2.0.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/stress.jar::/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar
INFO  13:04:11 JVM Arguments: [-ea, -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar, -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled, -XX:+UseThreadPriorities, -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42, -Xms512M, -Xmx512M, -Xmn100M, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xss256k, -XX:StringTableSize=1000003, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+UseTLAB, -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/cassandra/hotspot_compiler, -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000, -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled, -XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways, -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000, -XX:+UseCondCardMark, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199, -XX:+DisableExplicitGC, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra, -Dcassandra.storagedir=, -Dcassandra-foreground=yes]
WARN  13:04:13 Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
WARN  13:04:13 JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
ERROR 13:04:20 Directory /cassandra_data/data doesn't exist
ERROR 13:04:20 Has no permission to create /cassandra_data/data directory
```

ReplicationController:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
      app: cassandra
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      containers:
        - command:
            - /run.sh
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 0.1
          env:
            - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
              value: 512M
            - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
              value: 100M
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v8
          name: cassandra
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9042
              name: cql
            - containerPort: 9160
              name: thrift
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /cassandra_data
              name: data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You changed cassandra default data directory so first create data directory . Give permission to write and read to created new data directory or run cassandra as root . if you set credential for cassandra then provide user name and password also .